# jinja2exceptions TemplateNotFound: index.html with uwsgi but not flask run

Tags: flask, jinja2, uwsgi

I'm hosting a server with Alpine Linux on RPi3. It has many uwsgi plugins of which I have installed uwsgi-[ corerouter, router_redirect, sslrouter, http, router_http ] and obviously uwsgi

When I execute

```
export FLASK_APP=myapp.py
flask run
```

and in another virtual terminal

```
curl 127.0.0.1:5000
```

My page of index.html is printed.
But when I execute

```
uwsgi --wsgi-file myapp.py --callable app --master true --http-socket=0.0.0.0:2340
```

curl returns the above jinja2 exceptions templateNotFound

How to solve this. My directory structure is

```
-myapp.py
-templates
  -index.html
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting absolute paths with the line below solved this error. I guess for multiple processes, it is possible that they would be working in different directories. Setting absolute paths for the app prevents this.

```
app = Flask(__name__, template_folder="templates_path", static_folder="static_path")
```